# How can I use a ViewPager to display the same fragment but loaded with different data each time?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to set up a ViewPager to display the same template fragment but populated with different data after each swipe. I'm using dummy data here, but my problem is that the same data is being loaded after each swipe. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

Test:

```
public class Test {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private int c;

    public Test(String a, String b, int c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public static final Test[] testData = {
            new Test("Title 1", "Description 1", 1),
            new Test("Title 2", "Description 2", 2),
            new Test("Title 3", "Description 3", 3),
            new Test("Title 4", "Description 4", 4),
            new Test("Title 5", "Description 5", 5)
    };

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public int getC() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

TestFragment:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_ID = "Id";
    private int Id;
    private String a;
    private TextView aTV;
    private String b;
    private TextView bTV;
    private int c;
    private TextView cTV;

    public static TestFragment newInstance(int Id) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_ID, Id);

        TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);

        Id = (Integer) getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_ID);
        a = Test.testData[Id].getA();
        b = Test.testData[Id].getB();
        c = Test.testData[Id].getC();

        aTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.a);
        aTV.setText(a);

        bTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.b);
        bTV.setText(b);

        cTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.c);
        cTV.setText(String.valueOf(c));

        return view;
    }
}
```

ViewPagerActivity:

```
public class ViewPagerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return TestFragment.newInstance(position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 5;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting the *fragment arguments* of the `TestFragment` in which You have the `Id` variable but instead You are trying to get the data from the Intent Extras:

```java
Id = (Integer) getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_ID);
```

You should get the arguments that You have provided in the `newInstance` method of `TestFragment` this way:

```java
Id = getArguments().getInt(ARG_ID);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! Your answer did indeed help me, although there was a weird thing that happened, and I can't seem to figure out why it happened. In your solution, I was able to replace `Id = getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_ID);` with `Id = getArguments().getInt(ARG_ID);`, and it worked fine. However, when I used the real data, it only worked when I passed `ARG_ID` and did not work when I passed `EXTRA_ID`.

Comment: That's right, that was just a mistake on my side. It should have been `ARG_ID` because it is the key of the value you are trying to get from the bundle.

Comment: That's what I figured as well, but I just didn't get why it worked for me with the code I posted when I passed `EXTRA_ID`. On that note, I figure that I should ask one more question about this ViewPager, since it's sort of related. I'm trying to add buttons to the ViewPager that do the same thing as the ViewPager so that the user can either use the ViewPager or the buttons to flip left and right. However, the OnClickListener that I'm implementing does not work the first time I press the button and I have to press it again for it to work. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think that it is a topic for another question. I don't think I will be able to answer here, in the comments.

Comment: OK, I have asked it as a separate question. If you can, would you please answer it? I've been trying to fix it on my own without success.